# Removing assignment in SELECT clause affects value of other property

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, entity-framework-core, ef-core-6.0

### Issue

I have the following Linq query:

```
var query = from r in DbContext.Railcars
            where r.Facility.Company.CompanyCode == companyCode && r.Departure == null
            group r by r.Product into productGroup
            select new
                   {
                       Product = productGroup.Key,
                       Original = productGroup.Sum(r => (long)r.Volume),
                       Offloaded = productGroup.SelectMany(r => r.TruckRailcars).Sum(tr => (long)tr.Volume)
                   };
var x = query.ToList();
```

Here are the results:

[image]

These numbers are wrong. The `Original` values are too large.

### Modified

If I comment out the assignment to `Offloaded` in the `select` clause, I get different results.

[image]

These numbers are correct!

### SQL

The first version produces the following SQL.

```sql
DECLARE @__companyCode_0 nvarchar(80) = N'USRAILOGL';

SELECT [r].[Product], COALESCE(SUM(CAST([r].[Volume] AS bigint)), CAST(0 AS bigint)) AS [Original], COALESCE(SUM(CAST([t].[Volume] AS bigint)), CAST(0 AS bigint)) AS [Offloaded]
FROM [Railcars] AS [r]
INNER JOIN [Facilities] AS [f] ON [r].[FacilityId] = [f].[Id]
INNER JOIN [Companies] AS [c] ON [f].[CompanyId] = [c].[Id]
INNER JOIN [TruckRailcars] AS [t] ON [r].[Id] = [t].[RailcarId]
WHERE ([c].[CompanyCode] = @__companyCode_0) AND ([r].[Departure] IS NULL)
GROUP BY [r].[Product]
```

The second (correct) version produces the following SQL.

```sql
DECLARE @__companyCode_0 nvarchar(80) = N'USRAILOGL';

SELECT [r].[Product], COALESCE(SUM(CAST([r].[Volume] AS bigint)), CAST(0 AS bigint)) AS [Original]
FROM [Railcars] AS [r]
INNER JOIN [Facilities] AS [f] ON [r].[FacilityId] = [f].[Id]
INNER JOIN [Companies] AS [c] ON [f].[CompanyId] = [c].[Id]
WHERE ([c].[CompanyCode] = @__companyCode_0) AND ([r].[Departure] IS NULL)
GROUP BY [r].[Product]
```

### Question

It appears that the additional join to `TruckRailcars` is causing additional rows to be returned, which is increasing my totals. Given my original query, this doesn't seem quite right. I've [reported the issue to Microsoft](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/28483). But how else could I write this query?

Comment: Show your model. Looks like grouping is wrong.

Comment: Please select a tag for the ef-core version you're using (that's particularly important for ef-core questions).

Comment: @GertArnold: I already have 5 tags. But I'm using the very latest updates with .NET 6.0.

Comment: @JonathanWood, any chance to  see your model? Your query is definitely complex for SQL translation, I want to understand how to rewrite it even there is probably EF Core bug.